# Stackoverflow exception under IIS: Can I give a better error message?

Tags: c#, iis, stack-overflow

We have a service running under IIS that can crashed due to a stackoverflow. However, it wasn't obvious from the eventlog what had happened. All I see are

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.18444, time stamp: 0x52717f9a
```

and

```
A process serving application pool 'x' suffered a fatal communication error with the
Windows Process Activation Service. The data field contains the error number.
```

We have reasonable ideas how to fix the stackoverflow (switch some of our recursive methods to iterative ones). However, is there some way of logging the stackoverflow to the eventlog?

I understand you can't catch stackoverflows within .Net, but presumably IIS could handle this. E.g. If I run a console app with a deliberately engineered stackoverflow, I get

```
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

which is clear.

Also, Fast Fail Protection doesn't seem to be kicking in: Maximum Failures is set to 5, it seems to restart continually.

Comment: I presume the `The data field contains the error number.` will tell you the error number which when googled, will tell you that there is `StackOverflow?

Comment: can you show the code I wonder if you are stuck in an infinite loop somewhere.. could be some `recursive` call that's causing the issue..

Comment: @Chris: Actually, the exception code `0xC00000FD` seems to indicate stackoverflow. Maybe that is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use debug diags from msft.  This can be configured to create a process dump when there is a stack overflow.  Then you can load the dump into windbg and get the stack that caused the overflow.
Tess has lots of information on how to do this including training sessions on her blog
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/

Comment: too bad that the link is now broken ;/